# Divisible sum in pairs in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach

I am trying to solve hackerrank divisible sum in pairs problem with this code, yet it is given a 0 back as result?

```
div(6,3, [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]);

function div(n, k, ar) {
    var sum = 0;
    ar.forEach( (el, index) => {
        ar.forEach( (elem, indexS) => {
            console.log((index < indexS) && (el + elem % k === 0));
            if((index < indexS) && (el + elem % k === 0)) {           
                sum++;
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(sum);
}
```

each `forEach` is doing its job (checked it with `console.log`), yet I keep getting 0 as a result??

anyone can help, is much appreciated.

Comment: This might be silly but can you try `sum++;` instead of `sum ++;`?

Comment: try putting (el + elem) in braces like ( (el + elem ) % k === 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% has higher precedence, so use brackets

```
   Change   el + elem % k to (el + elem) % k
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your order of operations on (el+elem),

```js
function div(n,k,ar){
  var sum = 0;
  ar.forEach((ai, ii)=> {
        ar.forEach((aj, jj)=> {
            let isDiv = (ii < jj) && ((ai + aj) % k === 0);
            // console.log('isDiv',isDiv);
            if(isDiv){           
              sum ++;
            }
        })
  })
  return sum;
}
let sum = div(6,3, [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your if statement. By checking at the console.log, the condition always returns false, so the sum++ is never applied. I've added some comments hopefully this will help you!

```js
div(6,3, [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]);

function div(n,k,ar){
  var sum = 0;
  ar.forEach((el, index)=> {
        ar.forEach((elem, indexS)=> {
            console.log((index < indexS) && (el + elem % k === 0)); // this line is always false
            if((index < indexS) && (el + elem % k === 0)){    // meaning this condition is never true       
            sum ++; // will never be called
  
            }
        })
  })

console.log(sum); // returns 0, because value is never incremented
}
```